# How can I set up a shortcut on macOS Monterey to delete selected files?

Tags: macos, applescript, shortcuts-app, monterey

I have the following shortcut:
[image: Shortcut screenshot]
The delete action seems to run when I click the "Yes" button in the dialog, just like it should. I know this because I was asked for permission to allow it to run the first time I tested the shortcut. However, the file that I had selected in Finder was still not deleted!

I feel like I'm going crazy here...it took me **two hours** of Googling just to come up with this seemingly-simple combination of actions, and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?

MTIA for any advice/guidance given :-)

PS: In case it isn't obvious, I am a complete noob when it comes to Applescript or anything to do with the new Shortcuts feature in Monterey. It's been years since I last used a Mac so any answerers should please ELI5 :P Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you went to AppleScript first? By that, I only mean that this (deleting files) is easily done under the "unix" side of macOS via `rm`. Also - you didn't specify, but do you want to **delete**, or **move to Trash**?

Comment: @Seamus I *did* end up using a Bash script-based solution, as you can see in my answer below :-) The whole purpose of this shortcut is to avoid the Trash altogether, but with an extra "are you sure?" prompt to make the process foolproof. I've been living this way on Windows for decades (bypassing the Recycle Bin with a prompt), so I don't understand why there isn't a built-in way to do this on macOS. Oh well, it took the better half of a day, but I've got Apple bending to my will now :P

Comment: Ha ha - Good for you - Apple needs more bending. :)

Comment: LOL I agree 100%! Love their hardware but their software leaves a lot to be desired by someone who is new to it (or at least me) :P

Comment: I've been a mac user since 2010. IMHO, their software has always left a lot to be desired; lately, it is leaving more and more and more...  But yeah - love the hardware; my favorite Linux box is the old macbookpro from 2011!

Comment: @Seamus LOL nice to hear that kind of comment from an actual long-term user! Everyone I've ever spoken to at length about computers is either a hardcore Apple fan boy that wouldn't dare utter a single negative word about them, or the complete opposite in either the Linux or Windows camp :P But yeah, I had my 2011 MacBook Air for 5 years before selling it to a mate, and he still uses it to this day ^^ And I'm typing this on a 2020 M1 Air that words can't describe how much I love LOL.

Comment: Yeah - definitely a mixed experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @KevinGrabher and a bit more Googling, I managed to come up with the following partial solution:
[image]

This *mostly* works, but the keyboard shortcut that I've tried to set up in the right sidebar doesn't. I'll post a separate question about that and link to it from here when I'm done.

EDIT: It seems as though all that was needed to get the shortcut to work was a system restart! All good now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the input files directly by using "Get Variable" and then attaching the Delete function.

[image: Example Screenshot]

However, as a precaution macOS will still ask you another time if you want to allow the shortcut to delete the file, so you might want to handle the file deletion directly in the AppleScript using something like

```
if answer = "Yes" then
    tell application "Finder"
        delete file input
    end tell
end if
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the input is a single file, not a folder or multiple selected files so you'd have to take additional steps to handle those cases. Also, the files are not immediately deleted but instead moved to the trash. Personally I'd suggest thinking about going for a Shell Script solution instead.

Comment: Hmm...thanks for adding the "keep in mind..." part (and for the answer in general); I was afraid that may be the case! Is it really impossible (or much harder) to delete multiple files/folders in AppleScript? My knowledge of basic *nix commands like `rm -rf ...` is much better than my AppleScript knowledge, but I still wouldn't have a clue how to take the selected files/folders as input into a bash script. An example in either language would be very much appreciated. MTIA! :-)

Comment: Never mind, I managed to work it out myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Howe are you? I had a similar problem and wanted to delete files of certain folders and wrote an AppleScript as I think it is easier to use.

However, you might find this useful to delete files and use a repeat loop to change directories. It might not be the nicest code nor the most lean but works fine for me.

```
(*
Apple Scritp to Delete Files in all Startup and auto-launch Folders
    with dialog box to choose Delete or Cancle
    Uwe @UweTheSailor May 2022
*)

-- Variable Declaration Launch Deamons
set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:LaunchDaemons:"
-- Counter i increment to repeat loop (for loop)
set i to 1

-- Loop all folders and check if there are files in the Startup and Launch Folders:
repeat until i = 4
    -- Fill the List "listOfNames" with files in the folder:
    set listOfNames to {}
    tell application "Finder"
        set filelist to every file of the xyz
        repeat with currentFile in filelist
            set currentFileName to (the name of currentFile)
            copy currentFileName to the end of listOfNames
        end repeat
    end tell
    
    -- Only show dialog when Folder is empty (=content of listOfNames is Zero)!
    if length of listOfNames = 0 then
        display dialog "    There are " & length of listOfNames & " files in the folder: 
    " & xyz with title "Folder is empty!"
        
        -- Only offer Delete if there are files in the folder! 
    else if length of listOfNames > 0 then
        -- Display a dialog window with buttons and auto Cancel if no interaction after 10 seconds:
        set theButton to button returned of (display dialog "The Folder contains " & length of listOfNames & " files as follows: 
" & listOfNames with title "Found Files in the " & xyz with icon caution buttons {"Cancel", "Delete"} default button "Cancel" giving up after 10)
        -- Move all Files to the Bin if Button Delete is pressed
        if theButton is "Delete" then
            tell application "Finder"
                delete (every item of (xyz))
            end tell
        end if
    end if
    
    -- Increment i + 1 and move to the next folder
    set i to i + 1
    -- Update the variable xyz to the next folder
    if i = 2 then
        set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:StartupItems:"
    else if i = 3 then
        set xyz to alias "Macintosh HD:Library:LaunchAgents:"
    end if
end repeat
```

Let me know if that helps you!
Cheers!