# How can I test that an AppleScript received valid input?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, shortcuts-app, karabiner

### Background

I asked [How can I set up a shortcut on macOS Monterey to delete selected files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433669/how-can-i-set-up-a-shortcut-on-macos-monterey-to-delete-selected-files) and was *mostly* able to solve the problem with this:
[image: Shortcut screenshot]

Although the screenshot shows <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> as the assigned shortcut, I am actually using <kbd>F12</kbd>, since my MacBook Air doesn't have a <kbd>Del</kbd> key. I have this key mapped to <kbd>Del</kbd> in [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) in an attempt to get an experience like what I'm used to in Windows, i.e:

- Press <kbd>Del</kbd> (or <kbd>F12</kbd> in my case) on a selection in Finder: those files/folders are deleted (bypassing the Trash, but with a sanity check dialog, hence the AppleScript).
- Same key press in any other app, with the cursor in the middle of some text, deletes the next character to the right of the cursor.

When you've been a Windows power user for over 20 years you kinda take for granted how complicated the low-level programming for this functionality must be (or at least I do).
This hacky combination of a custom keyboard mapping + macOS Shortcut *kinda* works, but not in every situation.

When I'm trying to do the latter option above, the Finder service often takes precedence over the app that *actually has focus* and the result is an annoying dialog that I didn't expect, since I'm not even *actively* using Finder at the time.

### Question

How can I adapt my AppleScript to check that the `input` parameter is actually a valid collection of file/folder objects before even attempting to show the dialog?

I've tried a simple `if input ...` check, but unfortunately AppleScript doesn't seem to be that smart. When testing inside the Shortcuts editor, I get an error dialog saying `Can’t make {} into type boolean`.

What variable type is AppleScript expecting here? And how would I coerce such a type to a boolean? MTIA :-)

P.S.: I know I could probably create multiple complex command/s in Karabiner to map <kbd>F12</kbd> to some other key in the case of Finder being active, or <kbd>Del</kbd> in every other case, then assign the other key as my Shortcut hotkey, but that seems like reinventing the wheel. Nonetheless, if a Karabiner expert comes across this and can post a full JSON example of how to do that, I guess that would suffice for now.

Comment: BTW, there already is a shortcut for "Delete immediately, bypassing Trash" It's Cmd/Opt/Backspace. There's an 'are you sure' but no file list for multiple items [only for a single file] - presumably it assumes you can see the file list highlighted in the Finder right before you do it.

Comment: Interesting; thanks for the tip! That's too many keypresses for my liking though, and my last (Windows) laptop lacked a Del key too, so I used the same "remap F12" hack on that laptop and got used to it LOL. But I might try mapping Cmd+Opt+delete to a single key and see if I can get used to that. Thanks again! :D

Comment: btw, the nice keyboard symbols with <kbd> don't work in comments unfortunately;) You don't need a Delete key. 'file delete' is always Backspace, never Delete [Cmd/Delete just beeps, it's not a valid combo]. The actual Delete key on an extended keyboard is [text] Forward Delete, which can be replicated for a 'short' keyboard by Fn/Backspace. I'd always thought Cmd/Back or Cmd/Opt/Back to be simple one-handers, btw, either hand on the right-most modifiers - squish Cmd & Opt with a thumb.

Comment: btw, I hope this isn't coming over as 'terse'… I'm meaning it to be a friendly look around at how Mac does it - as you appear to be a competent user of 'computers' but new[ish] to Mac.

Comment: "...you appear to be a competent user of 'computers' but new[ish] to Mac". LOL yep, you hit the nail right on the head! Thanks for the tips, I'll try to get used to doing things the Mac way ;-) And no your comments didn't come off as rude or terse at all :-)

Comment: Most welcome - glad it didn't come over the wrong way, sometimes it's hard to read intent in text. Feel free to ask additional questions in the stack if you need more 'macishness' for your ported experience. Sometimes it's harder to have switched than to come fresh to Mac with no foreknowledge. No question is too simple or too foolish that it won't be of help to someone finding it via google & we're here to try make the transition easy :))

Comment: "Sometimes it's harder to have switched than to come fresh to Mac with no foreknowledge" - 100% agree, especially for someone like me. I get used to doing things a certain way and get easily confused/frustrated when I can't use a different OS in the same way. I have a fair amount of experience with "the big 3" but definitely much more Windows experience than anything else. So yeah that makes it hard. But I've decided to give getting used to macOS another try after buying an M1 MacBook Air for it's impressive hardware. Wish me luck! :D And yes I'll definitely ask here when I get stuck again ;-)

Comment: Good Luck! …& always remember - it's better to ask for how to achieve your goal than how to do what you *think* might achieve your goal;) i.e. avoid the old [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). All the best :) "I used to be able to do this like this on Windows. Is there a Mac equivalent?" is always a good start point, as people who use both OSes might already know both methods.